# Building Mendel Linux error for Coral Dev Board

Tags: google-coral, mendel-os, fakeroot

I'm trying to build Mendel Linux for Google Coral Dev Board on Ubuntu 20.04.

I followed the instructions step by step described in the https://coral.googlesource.com/docs/+/refs/heads/master/GettingStarted.md.

Аfter building the tree by the running `m`, I did not receive the image files required to the flash: `u-boot.imx`, `rootfs_arm64.img`.

The log contains the following lines with error:

```
Making install in mod
make[4]: Entering directory '/build/linux-imx-12/debian/build/build-tools/scripts/mod'
/build/linux-imx-12/debian/rules.d/scripts/mod/gendef.py /build/linux-imx-12/scripts/mod/modpost.c > modpost-opts.h
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libfakeroot-sysv.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/linux-imx-12/debian/build/build-tools/scripts/mod=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -I /build/linux-imx-12/debian/build/build-tools/scripts/mod -c -o modpost.o /build/linux-imx-12/debian/rules.d/scripts/mod/modpost.c
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/linux-imx-12/debian/build/build-tools/scripts/mod=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -Wl,-z,relro -o modpost modpost.o
/usr/bin/make -f /build/linux-imx-12/debian/rules.d/scripts/mod/Makefile.real TYPE=lsb-32 SOURCEDIR=/build/linux-imx-12/scripts/mod
```

The build ends with the lines:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/build/linux-imx-12'
 dpkg-genbuildinfo --build=full
 dpkg-genchanges -sa --build=full >../linux-imx_12-4_arm64.changes
dpkg-genchanges: info: including full source code in upload
 dpkg-source --after-build .
 lintian --profile=mendel ../linux-imx_12-4_arm64.changes
dpkg-buildpackage: info: full upload (original source is included)
N: 8 tags overridden (1 error, 7 warnings); 1 unused override
I: Copying back the cached apt archive contents
I: unmounting /rootdir/out/target/product/imx8m_phanbell/packages filesystem
I: unmounting /rootdir filesystem
I: unmounting dev/ptmx filesystem
I: unmounting dev/pts filesystem
I: unmounting dev/shm filesystem
I: unmounting proc filesystem
I: unmounting sys filesystem
I: cleaning the build env 
I: removing directory /rootdir/out/target/product/imx8m_phanbell/obj/PBUILDER/165726 and its subdirectories
I: Current time: Thu May  5 13:00:18 UTC 2022
I: pbuilder-time-stamp: 1651755618
touch /rootdir/out/target/product/imx8m_phanbell/.linux-imx-pbuilder-arm64
```

Package `fakeroot version 1.24` is currently installed.

I tried to preset `LD_PRELOAD`:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot/libfakeroot-sysv.so
```

and create symbolic link:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot/libfakeroot-sysv.so /usr/lib/libfakeroot-sysv.so
```

But it did not help.

I'm not sure that the build fails because of this error, but it happens right after this.

How can I solve this problem ?
Thank you.